# Paypal variable automatic billing request php

Tags: php, variables, paypal, paypal-ipn, billing

My IPN successfully receives notification (recurring_payment_profile_created) when a automatic billing agreement has been made via paypal buttons.

I get all the details like payer_id, recurring_payment_id, etc

What is the next step to take payment via code rather than via the paypal interface?

I thought it would be to call DoReferenceTransaction but I dont have the billing agreement to pass (REFERENCEID)

Is there a step I am missing (like calling SetExpressCheckout?)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using the USA API?

Comment: @mkmnstr I am using NVP/SOAP API - should I be looking at REST as we are taking payments in the UK?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how do I do this : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/manage-billing-plans/ via php code